# Incrementing id names sequentially on click

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here's what I'm trying to do: On a basic HTML page, Start by showing only one block of text and, on document click, have the next block of text fade in.

For instance, start with just the contents of `div id="fadeIn-0"`showing. On click, contents of `div id="fadeIn-1"` fade in. On next click, contents of `div id="fadeIn-2"` fade in, etc etc etc. They all have the class of `fadeIn`

Currently, my script.js looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0

 $('.fadeIn').each(function(index,par) {
      if(index>0) {
        $(par).hide();

    $(document).click(function() {
       counter+=1;
       $('#fadeIn-'+counter).fadeIn('slow');
     });
});
```

This works, but as I'm using more occurrences of .fadeIn-#s, I want to be able to have the class names increment automatically, instead of having to type each number the divs manually when first writing the page. I'm not even sure this is possible, but I figured it was worth a shot!

I'm really, really new to js/jquery, so thank you in advance for any help or guidance you might have.

Comment: You skipped `div id="fadeIn-1`

Comment: just corrected it - that was a typo :) thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of them have the same class `.fadeIn`, and they are arranged sequentially in the document, you may not need to use their `id`s at all.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fadeIn').hide();
    $(document).on('click',function() {
        $('.fadeIn:hidden:first').fadeIn('slow');
    })
    .click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
$('.fadeIn').each(function(index,par) {
  if(index>0) {
    $(par).hide();

  //$(par).addClass('fadeIn-'+index);
  $(par).attr('id', 'fadeIn-'+index);

$(document).click(function() {
   counter+=1;
   $('#fadeIn-'+counter).fadeIn('slow');
 });
```